# Strapi Warning: Some of the provided components in xxx are not related to the entity

Tags: admin, strapi

**I get this error whenever I try to save content in the second locale**

It saves fine in the default locale, but when I change to the second locale, add content, and save, I get that error.
It differs depending on the page but it is generally the same.
This is happening in strapi admin
help me, please

This didn't happen before why now?